# Windows 8 black screen with mouse pointer after login

Tags: windows-8

I restarted my system today and after logging in, i could see see nothing but a black screen with mouse pointer. I can start task manager via alt+ctrl+del, Task manager and msconfig show fine but when i try to run 'explorer' nothing happens.
In safe mode everything seems fine.

I do not have any system restore points and repair options from the DVD show "this option is not available for the selected OS"

I've also updated my graphic drivers. Didn't help

Comment: if safemode works fine, you have a buggy software that causes it. Do a clean boot and enable back some software until you found the cause: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Comment: i have disabled all startup programs. I can not uninstall any because safe mode doesn't have the installer service started

Comment: @SagarJuneja - If you have no restore points then you are out of luck.  Restore points are enabled by default and created when updates are applied automatically why don't you have any?

Comment: i would say it's because Restore Points start hogging more and more space than they actually need. I remember them using 20 GB when I disabled them some time last year. Anyway, as for your issue, if this is a Desktop try removing the Gfx card and putting it back. If that doesn't work... Refresh and reset is your best bet. Oh, also take a look at the BIOS.. could be some BIOS setting here and there

Comment: @Gutsygibbon: If your current installation is stable and you do not want to restore to an earlier point, you can disable System Restore to delete all existing restore points, then re-enable it and save a snapshot of the current system state. In any case, a proper backup to an external drive is always better compared to this.

Comment: @Karan I prefer doing backups on external. System restore is not worth the hassle. I personally hate losing HDD space to random stuff...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue as well. I found that I can use `CTRL` + `ALT` + `DEL` at the black screen. This allows me to start the Task Manager. Within the Task Manager select New Task (RUN) from the File menu. Type CMD and select the check box to run this command as an administrator. Within the command prompt, type `sfc/scannow` and let it scan your system. Once completed, reboot the machine by pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `DEL` again and select restart from the Power button on the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like explorer took a dump. Rather than troubleshoot for hours, just refresh the PC with the built in utility. All your documents and data will be left intact and the operating system will be re-installed completely. I LOVE this feature in WIN 8 and have used it several times. Note that you will have to reload programs but this is a minor inconvenience for getting a fresh OS back on your HD knowing there arent any other bugs lurking in the background.

Boot up to the login screen, hold down SHIFT and reboot the PC to get into the advanced boot menu. Here you will find all kinds of goodies to troubleshoot, refresh or reset the system back to defaults.